# Add onclick method to dynamically created table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that is populated with a list of users from a database using ajax and next to each of the users names I have an expand/minimize icon that I want the user to be able to click on to show more information about that user.

Example:
HTML table

```
<table class = "table" name="pData" id="<?php echo $patientId ?>">
</table>
```

Javascript to populate table: (on successful ajax call iterate through each user and add the following to the table for each one)

```
tableData = "<tr>
             <td>
            <img src = 'expandIcon.png' onclick='showUserInfo("+UserId+", 'Max')'/>       
            </td>";
tableData += "<td colspan = '2'>"+userName+"</td>";
tableData += "<td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp</td>
               </tr>";

$('.table').append(tableData);
```

My table is being created the way I want it to but the onclick events never happen and showUserInfo isn't ever called. How do I fix this so it will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class in the element like this:

```
tableData = "<tr>
              <td>
              <img class='anyclass' id="+UserId+" src = 'expandIcon.png'/>
             </td>";
tableData += "<td colspan = '2'>"+userName+"</td>";
tableData += "<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>";
$('.table').append(tableData);
```

then write jquery event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(img.anyclass).live('click',function(){

showUserInfo(this.id, 'Max');


});

});
```

Comment: you are welcome, and i am happy that it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Close the img tag properly

```
"<tr><td><img src = 'expandIcon.png' onclick='showUserInfo("+UserId+", 'Max')'/></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and found you have problem with concatenation:

```
tableData = "<tr><td><img src = 'expandIcon.png' onclick='showUserInfo(\'"+UserId+"\', \'Max\')'></td>";
tableData += "<td colspan = '2'>"+userName+"</td>";
tableData += "<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp</td> </tr>";
$('.table').append(tableData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'event delegation' which is more efficient when you have large number of rows in the table element.

First create your rows:

```
var newRow = '<tr><td><img src='expandIcon.png' /></td></tr>';
```

Now add it to the end of the table:

```
$('#yourtable tr:last').after(newRow);
```

Dynamically bind the event handler to the row(or image):

```
$('#yourtable').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
    // do your stuff here
});
```

Say you have 100 rows in your table, if you follow normal approach, handlers will be attached to 100 elements. With event delegation, only one element is attached with the event handler.